# Move Add to cart button next to More info image in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

On this page http://www.qualityhangers.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1818 I want to move the "add to cart" image next to "more info". So detach this

```
<a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=QH1225272">
<img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/210/images/buttons/btn_addtocart_small.gif">
</a>
```

and attach in front of

```
<a class="smalltext colors_text" href="http://www.QUALITYHANGERS.COM/Natural-Wood-Suit-Combo-Hanger-17-p/qh1225272.htm">
<img border="0" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/210/images/Bullet_MoreInfo.gif">
</a>
```

Shall I assign a ID to image tag Bullet_MoreInfo.gif?

Comment: Both the images in different `<tr>`, can not you just move the `add to cart` image next to `more info`?

Comment: @codef0rmer I dont have control or the code from where it displays i can just Javascript to that HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fetching all the `<a>` tags (add to cart buttons) based on their HREF (as there is no unique CSS class attached to it) and looking for `<a>` tag (more info button) which has to be its immediate sibling (indirect).

```
$('a[href^="/ShoppingCart.asp"]').each(function () {
   var $addToCart = $(this),
   $moreInfo = $(this).parents('td[width="100%"]').parent().next().find('a');
   $addToCart.insertAfter($moreInfo);
});
```

Demo: Go to your webpage and run the above code in the console.

Note: Make sure you always have the same markup, you have to modify `parents(selector)` in `$moreInfo` otherwise as per your need.

Comment: I added that code but nothing happens at http://tinyurl.com/cv5xbqs please advise.

Comment: You missed `$` in `var addToCart`. Change `var addToCart = $(this)` to `var $addToCart = $(this)`. If you've checked the firebug console then you would have seen the error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: $addToCart is not defined"